# Calculate $ \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\ x^2 -\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\ln(1+\sin^2x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2 -\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1}$$ 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\ln(1+\sin^2x)}$$ 
Please if you can help me in the two limits.

Answer (score 1):

Hints.

i) For $x>0$, we have that
$$\frac{x^2 -\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}-1}=\frac{x^{1/2}(x^{3/2} -1)}{x^{1/2}-1}=x^{1/2}(x+x^{1/2}+1).$$

ii) We have that $a^b=\exp(b\ln a)$ and
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\ln(1+\sin^2x)}=
\lim_{x\to 0} \exp\left(\ln(1+\sin^2x)\cdot (-\ln(x))\right)\\
=\lim_{x\to 0} \exp\left(-x^2\ln(x)\cdot\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\cdot \frac{\ln(1+\sin^2x)}{\sin^2x}\right).$$
Now evaluate these (simpler) limits,
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=?$$ 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+\sin^2x)}{\sin^2x}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=?$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} x^2\ln(x)=?$$

Comment: Thank you but I do not understand where it comes t, why did your replacement

Comment: I do not quite understand what you meant to do there

Comment: Well not quite understand what you wanted to do you could make the steps I please, I do not quite understand another form of education are in romania

Comment: I get up there but you could tell me what exp

Comment: @Dan Balan See my edited answer.

Comment: @Dan Balan $\exp(x)=e^x$.

Comment: ln(1+t)/t=1 ok?

Comment: where have you realized exp
?

Comment: could you give me exercise 1, the radical, not quite understand?

Comment: @Dan Balan Yes $\ln(1+t)/t\to 1$. If you do not like radicals replace $x^{1/2}$ with $t$.